# Symfony 4 services local binding in different environments

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have to bind parameters with different values in different environments, and having problems with this.

I was trying this:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $param: 'param for PROD'

# config/services_dev.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $param: 'param for DEV'

# src/Controller/SomeController.php
class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function example($param)
    {
        echo $param;
    }
}
```

But it forces me to have all the services defined in both of **services.yaml** and **services_dev.yaml** files, otherwise it does not work.

I would like to have a **services.yaml** shared for any environment, and only override the custom services/bindings etc, not have two identical files with all services listed in them for changing one binding value.

---

The real problem is that I have to create two http clients (real and a dummy) with same interface, in production load the real one, and in development load the dummy, Symfony 4-s autowiring allows me to inject the interface in a controller and choose which client to use in binding:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            'ClientInterface': '@real_client'
    # More services here...

# config/services_dev.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            'ClientInterface': '@dummy_client'
    # Here I don't want to have another copy of the services, 
    # but it does not work without them

# Controller
public function someMethod(ClientInterface $client)
{
    // ...
}
```

In Symfony 2 I was able to extend services.yml and in services_dev.yml only define the specific values I wanted to override/add, but in Symfony 4 **services_dev.yaml** can not use services from **services.yaml** and I have to keep my services identical in two different files which is pain.

Anny suggestions?

Thank you.

---

I'm updating the post again with a real example:

## services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    app.access_token: '%env(string:APP_ACCESS_TOKEN)%'
    app.aws_version: '%env(string:AWS_VERSION)%'
    app.aws_profile: '%env(string:AWS_PROFILE)%'
    app.aws_region: '%env(string:AWS_REGION)%'
    app.aws_queue_url_creation: '%env(string:AWS_QUEUE_URL_CAMPAIGN_CREATION)%'
    app.aws_queue_url_edition: '%env(string:AWS_QUEUE_URL_CAMPAIGN_EDITION)%'
    app.redis_host: '%env(string:REDIS_HOST)%'
    app.redis_port: '%env(string:REDIS_PORT)%'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.
        bind:
            App\Service\MessageSenderServiceInterface: '@App\Service\MessageSenderSqsService'

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    # Authenticators
    App\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator:
        arguments:
            - "%app.access_token%"

    # Clients
    App\Client\AwsSqsClient:
        arguments:
            - "%app.aws_version%"
            - "%app.aws_profile%"
            - "%app.aws_region%"

    App\Client\RedisClient:
        arguments:
            - "%app.redis_host%"
            - "%app.redis_port%"

    # Services
    App\Service\MessageSenderSqsService:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Client\AwsSqsClient'
            - '@App\Client\RedisClient'
            - "%app.aws_queue_url_creation%"
            - "%app.aws_queue_url_edition%"

    App\Service\MessageSenderRedisService:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Client\RedisClient'
```

## services_dev.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: services.yaml }

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.
        bind:
            App\Service\MessageSenderServiceInterface: '@App\Service\MessageSenderRedisService'
```

## Controller.php

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/dummy")
     */
    public function dummyEndpoint(MessageSenderServiceInterface $messageSender)
    {
        echo get_class($messageSender); exit;
    }
}
```

And the echo from controller for both envs (prod and dev) is

```
App\Service\MessageSenderSqsService
```

But if I copy whole node "services" form services.yaml to services_dev.yaml and only change the binding config, it works fine and says that the injected class is:

```
App\Service\MessageSenderRedisService
```

---

I've just noticed that if I don't touch the "_defaults" node, it works as expected, the problems start only when I want to override the _defaults node of services...

Answer (score 1):

You can define parameters in `parameters` section of `config.yml` and overwrite this parameters in `config_dev.yml`.

```
# config.yml
imports:
    # ...
parameters:
    parameter_1: value 1
    parameter_2: value 2
    # ...
framework:
    # ...

# config_dev.yml
imports:
    # ...
parameters:
    parameter_1: dev value 1
    # ...
framework:
    # ...
```

This parameters can be used used in `service.yml` as:

```
# service.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $param: '%parameter_1%'
```

Comment: Hello Łukasz,
Thank you for a quick reply.
The problem is that when I want to have services.yaml and services_dev.yaml, I have to maintain two copys of same service trees, I can not have one tree and extend it in different environments overriding only some particular nodes. In other words, I can not separe the same node in two different yaml files, the framework is not merging them. The example that you have will work in Symfony 2, but have you tried it with Symfony 4?
P.S. I use Symfony4/skeleton

Comment: if you are using different env maybe you should think of using ENV params?
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-runtime-environment-variables

Comment: Yes, I use them. But there is a part of config which is almost a part of code, and once configured, it is changed very few times. I want to configure it for a long time use and in every instance of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem was only in overriding the "_defaults" node (which I was touching in order to have different "bind" configs in the project).

Extending services.yaml without overriding **_defaults**, everything works as expected. And the solution is to have different configuration for services with their bindings by environment, and have "_defaults" only in services.yaml.

If we override the "_defaults" in other files, we'll have to redefine all the services too.

Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

1.Don't use `bind` and write different service configs for different environments

```
# services.yaml
App\Controller:
  arguments:
    - "@client"

# services_dev.yaml
App\Controller:
  arguments:
    - "@dummy_client"
```

2.Use `bind` and create service alias in each environment's `services.yaml`:

```
# services.yaml
services:
  some.client:
    alias: "@client"

# services_dev.yaml    
services:
  some.client:
    alias: "@dummy_client"
```

3.Just configure only one `ClientInterface` service per environment:

```
# services.yaml
App\ClientInterface:
  class: App\RealClient

# services_dev.yaml
App\ClientInterface:
  class: App\DummyClient
```

4.Use factory which will create this client depends on environment (but this is not very good practice as for me)

```
# services.yaml
App\ClientInterface:
  factory: ["@App\ClientFactory", create]
  arguments:
    - '%kernel.environment%'

class ClientFactory 
{
    public function create(string $env): ClientInterface
    {
        if ($env === 'dev') {
            return new DummyClient();
        } else {
            return new Client();
        }
    }
}
```

5.In your case, when you have so much services and you want to inject same service in all of them, you can use option #3 or you can create one interface for all of them and use `_instanceof`:

```
# services.yaml
_instanceof:
  App\SomeCommonInterface:
    calls:
      - method: setSomeService # interface's method
        arguments:
          - '@service'

# services_dev.yaml
_instanceof:
  App\SomeCommonInterface:
    calls:
      - method: setSomeService
        arguments:
          - '@dummy_service'
```

Comment: Hi Nikita Leshchev
Thanks for yor reply. First 3 options I like, and I was using the option 2 in my project. But I have another 40-50 services more that are exactly the same for any environment and I want to share them between multiple environments, there are only 2-3 that differs, no more.
I am looking for the solution to share all these 40-50 services.

Comment: @Irakli OK, I added one more option for you. However, I don't understand why the third option is not suitable for you?

Comment: Hi @Nikita again, and again thank You for your time and interest. The problem is that I don't want to list all these 44 services in both "services.yaml" and "services_dev.yaml" files repeatedly. Because every change I made in the future will require to maintain this 2 files with same config of all 44 services. And if I create new environments, like "test" or "staging" or any other cases, I will have to clone this config as well for them.

Comment: I am looking for a way to create 1 shared services.yaml file and in each environment override only the needed part of config that must be custom, like it was made in Symfony 2. I think there must be a way of doing this in Symfony 4 too.

Comment: And well, when I place all these services in services.yaml and include it in services_dev.yaml it's ok, but when I want to override any service in services_dev.yaml, I run into problems: The "services" node from services_dev.yaml completely replaces the content of services.yaml and I can not merge config from 2 different files.

Comment: And with option 3 - I have to define dependencies repeatedly for "App\RealClient" and "App\DummyClient" in both of services.yaml and services_dev.yaml before I can use them.

Comment: @Irakli that's strange, Symfony must autowire your `App\ClientInterface` service without redefining other services which use it. BTW can you show `_defaults` section of your `services.yaml`?

Comment: Yes, the services without arguments are autowired, but for custom config it requires to define them in all the environments repeatedly, without option to use services from one env to another

Comment: @Irakli could you please share `_defaults` node of your `services.yaml` and show constructor of one of your services which should accept client object?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll update my post with code as soon as I can (max in 1-1,5 hours).

Comment: @Irakli try to remove 'imports' from your services_dev.yaml